# PHP preg_match() ungreedy match issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use PHP pattern modifier "U" to invert the default greedy behavior with preg_match(). However, it doesn't work the way I want. My code:

```
$str = '<p>
<div><a aaa
    <a href="a.mov"></a>
  </div>
</p>';

$needle = "a.mov";

$pattern = "/\<a.*".preg_quote($needle, "/").".*\<\/a\>/sU";

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I'm trying to match on

```
<a href="a.mov"></a>
```

But this chunk of code returns me

```
<a aaa
    <a href="a.mov"></a>
```

Can someone shed me some light of where I did wrong?

Comment: your $matches variable doesn't equal anything, does it? How do you print it when its not initialized

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags     and then rewrite this to use DOM operations instead of Regexes. Your broken `<a aaa` tag demonstrates why regexes cannot be used reliably on HTML - html is **NOT** a regular language.

Comment: @Grigor: it's initialized/populated by preg_match

Answer (score 2):

Well, in more general sense, you did wrong when trying to parse HTML with regexps, but regarding the snippet of code you have provided, the problem is that the ungreedy modifier tells `*`, `+` and `{n,}` to stop as soon as they are happy instead of going all the way.

So it essentially affects where the matching ends instead of where it begins - "ungreedy" is *not* intended to mean "give me the shortest" match possible.

You can kind of like fix this particular example using `mU` modifiers instead of `sU`, so that `.` don't match new lines.

Comment: +1.  "greedy" and "non-greedy" are misnomers.  If we called them "eager" and "reluctant" instead, we might prevent some of this confusion.  It seems like everybody has to learn this lesson the hard way.  (FYI, there's no need to add the `m` modifier; just remove the `s`.)

Answer (score 0):

My array is turning up empty as well. You have to be careful about linebreaks when you try to use Regex with HTML. There may be an issue with single line mode.

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

I've successfully parsed HTML with regex but I wouldn't do it going forward. Look into

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You will never look back.